# SQL query that returns a date

Tags: sql, oracle

My DB contains a period(month) and a year - I am trying to convert it to a date. I don't care for the actual day of the month so I have just made it "1" (the 1st of the month).

In my code I had to convert the "13th" period to the 12th because of the 12 months of the year, so my decode did that part... Ultimately, I want it to return as a date. I have a concatenation to make it 'look' like a date, but not actually a date.

What i do with the data is query it and return it in Excel for further manipulation. When imported to Excel, it does not import as a date nor does it let me convert to a date format.

```
SELECT DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL.FY_DC || '/' || 
   decode(DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL.PER_DC,1,1,2, 2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,12)||
   '/01' as "Date"
FROM AMS.DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL
```

There has to be an easier or more effective way to do this!

Comment: Please provide some sample data for the FY_DC and PER_DC fields.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but are you sure 'period' equates to 'month' if your values go up to 13; they aren't say 4-week periods? And/or offset from the calendar months?

Comment: Yes, period is the month. The 13th 'month' is to capture straggling entries that don't make it in the December period, but belong to the year - The team came up with the 13th month idea to allow for these entries to be made in January of the following year. - Good follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no much simpler way. `DECODE` is fine for converting month 13 to month 12, but you use it a bit too complicated. Then you shouldn't rely on session settings, but explicitly tell the DBMS the date format your assembled string represents. Use `TO_DATE` with the appropriate format.

```
select 
  to_date(fy_dc || to_char(decode(per_dc, 13, 12, per_dc), '00') || '01', 'yyyymmdd') 
    as "Date"
from ams.dia_project_detail dia_project_detail;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - As a new coder I believe I was over complicating the query. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `least()`:

```
SELECT (DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL.FY_DC || '/' || 
        LEAST(DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL.PER_DC, 12) ||
        '/01'
       ) as "Date"
FROM AMS.DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL DIA_PROJECT_DETAIL;
```